# How should one update/return value from a callback function?

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, callback

I have registered callback via:
`SetWindowLongW(hWindow, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)WindowCallback);`

I receive messages there without problem. I have if() style code inside of callback which looks like this:

```
if (MSG == 1)
{

   *boolptr = true;
   ...
} else if(MSG == 2) {
  if (*boolptr == true)
    return;

   // do stuff
}
```

Variables are defined like so (globaly, under #includes right..)

> ```
> volatile bool         boolVar = false;
> volatile bool*        volatile boolptr = &boolVar;
> ```

If I wait for *boolptr to be TRUE in main() all is fine, but if I wait for it inside of same callback where it should change, it doesnt work. Obviously I don't understand some concept here so I ask for assistance or some explanation why its not working.

MSG with value of 2 always arives first, then after some processing MSG with value of 1. After some time same thing happens but I do not wan't to do same processing and waste CPU cycles thus I need to know if MSG[1] is following it and just return. I hope you understand me.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing - what do you mean by "waiting"? The code you listed are not waiting on the flag. However, if your "wait" is something like while (*boolptr) Sleep(1000); then your WndProc will not peek up the MSG(1) unless you DoEvents in the loop. Another reason could be MSG(2) is never fired.

Comment: Consider eliminating the bool and bool* variables. Instead use a PreviousMSG variable. That should let you check for the condition of interest with just one if statement.

Comment: @Codism, I need to wait because for the first run I need to process code in MSG[2] part, so I wait for a few seconds expecting MSG[1], if not received I do processing in MSG[2]. But if I do receive it and I know I did (I set messagebox) I can't capture that bool. Hope you understand now.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP, any reference on MSDN? If its correct answer I can just set it like one.

Comment: MSDN is not relevant - it is just program logic with a variable you create. if(MSG == 2 && PreviousMSG == 1) { PreviousMSG = 2; return;} if that is the condition you are trying to detect.

Comment: Its not PreviousMSG, its NextMSG in that context, but, how can I do that if only 1 MSG is received per callback instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description leaves a lot of details out, however I think I understand what you want.
The last parameter of CreateWindow() API function can be used to pass a pointer to your callback to some external variable:

```
// MAKE SURE this variable stays in scope throughout the lifetime of your window !
// Make it global or static
bool myVar;  

// let's create an overlapped window of some class with size 400 x 300 
HWND hWnd = CreateWindow("My class name", "My Title", 
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER| WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION |
    WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
    0,0, 400, 300, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), &myVar);
```

Then in the callback, you access it in WM_CREATE message:

```
// ... start of your callback

// get a pointer to your variable here and use it in all messages
// *except* WM_CREATE that sets it during window instance creation
bool *pMyVar = (bool *)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

switch(uMsg)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        // get your pointer from the CREATESTRUCT passed in
        // and store it in the user data area of your window class
        // note: your WNDCLASS should have its cbWndExtra = sizeof(void *);
        CREATESTRUCT *pC = (CREATESTRUCT *)lParam;
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG)pC->lpCreateParams);
        // .... 
    }
    break;

    case 1 :  // VERY bad choice for a message, use WM_USER+1 instead
        *pMyVar = true;
    break;
// ... rest of your callback
```

is this what you wanted?

EDIT: Ok, here is the class you wanted to see:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() : _hasRun(false) { }

    void DoStuff(HWND hW, UINT uMsg)
    {
        if (!_hasRun)
        {
            _hasRun = true;
            // ... do your work here, you have the window handle and the message
        }
    }

private:
    bool _hasRun;
};
```

now, in your main create an instance of this class and keep it in a static or global variable:

```
MyClass *pC = new MyClass;
```

then, pass this to the callback as I show in the beginning, and then call it always. The DoStuff member function will check the message and do what you want based on what message it is, once. Even if you keep it in a global and always call this global from the callback, the functionality will be the same.

```
// ... callback code before you handle any message
pC->DoStuff(hWnd, uMsg);
// ... rest of callback code
```

Comment: I don't create window the way you do, thus I dont process WM_CREATE msg. I got in a deadlock because of that I think. Should I change CreateWindow call or not? Everything else makes sense.

Comment: This method creates a modeless window, and the rest of the code continues so you can then enter the message loop. If you are creating a modal window (e.g. MessageBox) then the call wil not return since it creates its own message loop until the window is destroyed. Which method do you use, and why do you get into a deadlock ? 
Also, every message in the callback has to execute and return to the message loop so other messages can be processed. If you enter a wait loop in the callback, your current thread will freeze until you return from the callback.

Comment: I think I can't use your solution, WM_CREATE is 0x1 and it will not work in my case even if I make it work. Any other solution (not related to Window creation) CreateWindowEx(NULL, "tooltips_class32", NULL, NULL, 5, 5, 1, 2, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

Comment: So technically speaking DNT, I can't do this because I neeed to wait a few seconds for possible MSG[1]? Well I can't do it in the callback itself that is. For the record, I had MessageBox() call in both MSG cases, both of them showed one after another. Thats normal behavior I think.

Comment: I think you can. In WM_CRETE above, you can add this line bool *pVar = (bool *)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA); after the SetWindowLongPtr(...) call, and then do *pVar = true; there. This is equivalent to your code. Then replace case 1: as I typed it, with your other message and test. However, within a thread, windows employs cooperative multitasking for its windows using a message loop, so you need to return from the callback and not wait there. A wait can be implemented using a timer (WM_TIMER) to count how much time has passed since you set your value to 'true'.

Comment: Another way, is by putting the code you don't want to run all the time within a class, instantiate it ahead of time, and add your bool variable there as a member. Then pass the myclass * (the instance) to the callback, and let the callback call pmyClass->doStuff() call every time also passing the message as a parameter to the pmyClass->doStuff(..) member function. This function can then check the instance bool myVar member and set it to true the first time it executes, and just return from then on.

Comment: I like the last idea, because is perfect I guess. Nice thinking DNT. But there is a problem. I don't get the WM_CREATE message for some reason(see my CreateWindowEx call, I found it on Google and I think I need to create normal visible window with WNDCLASS instance). Once I do all I will paste results here. If you can c/p some class code to your answer or make new one so I can accept it. Thanks!